# ASP.net webdevelopment problem with web.config(?) on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, web-config

**SOLUTION: `<allow users="*"/>` changed to `<allow users="?"/>` did the trick for me.**

I have a problem that started to occur when i moved my asp.net website to my webserver (Windows Webserver 2008 R2 - IIS7).

I use VS2010 and run the project asp.net configuration and set deny all on root folder on my website.

Then when accessing the website externally i was correctly forwarded to /Account/Login.aspx but then the css file was not loaded.

So i added a allow all on the /Styles folder.

Still same problem.

If i login and then logout the css seems to load..

I dont really know what to look for here, is it a web.config problem, iis7 config problem or something else?

This is the web.config located at /Account/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="~/Styles/Site.css">  
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

And this is my websites base web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="~/Styles/Site.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="halldbConnectionString"/>
    <remove name="ApplicationServices"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="halldbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Väljhall.aspx"
timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
                    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There are tutorials how to move from iis6 to iis7..

Comment: Do you have another web.config file at the root  of your website?

Comment: @ub1k Im not moving it from iis6 to iis7.

Comment: @JuliusA Added my base web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<allow users="*"/>
```

changed to

```
<allow users="?"/>
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all please explore what requests to the css files respond. (Is it 404, 500, 302 response codes). You can do it with any http watcher like [HttpAnalyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/).

If css files response contains the information that request was not authorize - try to set AppPool to classic mode

Comment: It seems if i in iis7 change .NET trust level from "Full Internal" to high or medium (only tried those 2) then it loads correctly.

Comment: I thought the web.config i had in my website project was the ones ruling the site?